Android Leanback back button press does not stop video fragment
Hey all I am having an issue with closing my PlaybackVideoFragment that extends VideoSupportFragmentafter I press my back button on my remote.
The code I have to fire when the back button is pressed is this (the playerView.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener):
@OptIn(markerClass = UnstableApi.class)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MainFragment.movie = (Movie) getActivity().getIntent().getSerializableExtra(MOVIE);

    long cacheMaxSize = 90 * 1024 * 1024;
    File cacheRoot = getContext().getExternalCacheDir() != null ? getContext().getExternalCacheDir() : getContext().getCacheDir();
    File cacheDir = new File(cacheRoot, "media");
    SimpleCache simpleCache = new SimpleCache(cacheDir, new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(cacheMaxSize), new StandaloneDatabaseProvider(getContext()));

    DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory();

    CacheDataSource.Factory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSource.Factory()
            .setCache(simpleCache)
            .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(httpDataSourceFactory)
            .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR);

    ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory mediaSourceFactory = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory);

    DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setBufferDurationsMs(8 * 1024, 64 * 1024, 50, 1024)
            .build();

    ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getContext())
            .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
            .setLoadControl(loadControl)
            .build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        playerView.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener((v, event) -> {
            //Handle BACK button
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                getActivity().finish();
                //playerView.hideController(); //Hide mediaController,according to your needs, you can also called here onBackPressed() or finish()
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    playerView.setUseController(true);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(MainFragment.movie.getVideoUrl());
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);

    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    player.addListener(pbl());
    player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF);
    player.prepare();
    player.play();
}

This does take me back to my main screen but I can still here the video playing in the background (I hear the audio just don't see the video).
The way I am calling the video fragment is by this:
public class PlaybackActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    public static ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    public static PlayerView playerView;
    public static Activity activity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        activity = this;
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.amPrgbrLoading);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new PlaybackVideoFragment())
                .commit();
    }    
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

From the post, I see that you're using ExoPlayer library to play media. You expect that when user presses the Back button, the player should be stopped and navigate user back to main screen.
Root cause: When user presses the Back button, you just finish the activity without releaseing the ExoPlayer
Solution: Based on documentation of ExoPlayer at Release the player section.

It's important to release the player when it's no longer needed, so as to free up limited resources such as video decoders for use by other applications. This can be done by calling ExoPlayer.release.

Therefore, you need to release the ExoPlayer before finishing the current activity. Please follow the step 1 and step 2 below and give it a try.
// Step 1. Add final modifier here
final ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getContext())
        .setMediaSourceFactory(mediaSourceFactory)
        .setLoadControl(loadControl)
        .build();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    playerView.addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener((v, event) -> {
        // Handle BACK button
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Step 2. Release ExoPlayer
            player.release;

            getActivity().finish();
            // playerView.hideController(); //Hide mediaController,according to your needs, you can also called here onBackPressed() or finish()
        }
        return true;
    });
}

